# waveOutPrepareHeader returns INVALPARAMS

Tags: c#, audio, windows-ce

I've been trying to track this down for a while but I'm at a loss as to where to look next.  Whenever I call waveOutPrepareHeader() I get INVALPARAMS indicating "The buffer's base address is not aligned with the sample size."

I am currently preparing my header from the data after the "data" tag (and length) from the file using the method found via MSDN.

```
    public Wave.SystemError Read(BinaryReader rdr, uint readLength)
    {
        dwBufferLength = readLength;
        byte[] data = new byte[readLength];
        rdr.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

        if (lpData == IntPtr.Zero)
            lpData = Memory.LocalAlloc(Memory.LMEM_FIXED,
               (uint)data.Length);

        if (lpData == IntPtr.Zero)
            return Wave.SystemError.NOMEM;

        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, lpData, data.Length);

        return Wave.SystemError.NOERROR;
    }
```

All the parameters of the class are zeroed out before use, after calling this function on a wave file I get

```
dwBufferLength = 32768
dwBytesRecorded = 0
dwFlags = 0
dwLoops = 0
dwUser = 0
lpData = 384656
lpNext = 0
reserved = 0
```

when passed into

```
return waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, 
                            ref headerBuffer[buffIndex],
                            (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(headerBuffer[buffIndex]));
```

where headerBuffer[buffIndex] is the abovementioned WAVEHDR I get 11 (MMSYSERR_INVALPARAM).  I've checked and my hWaveOut and size seems to be sane so I'm forced to conclude the problem is with the header but I can't figure out what is wrong or even what to check.

What do I need to do to fix this error, or failing that, what can I check to see what is causing it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you point to some documentation for `WavePrepareHeader`?  All i could find was `WaveInPrepareHeader`

Comment: Oh, that is a PInvoke to waveOutPrepareHeader.  I'll edit my question to make this more clear.  Documentation for that is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908929.aspx

Comment: New piece of info.  I tried porting this code over to non-CE to see if there would be any difference, and the same code (other than swaps of the dlls the PInvokes are pointing to) got past waveOutPrepareHeader without returning any error.  Not sure what this means for what the issue is but it seems pertinent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being not an issue with lpData (which was being allocated properly by LocalAlloc), but an issue with the way that the WAVEHDR structure itself was being passed to the PInvoked waveOutPrepareHeader.

Most material on waveOut (even for C#) has you passing in an object of the header's type.  But in order to stop getting the error, I had to make a block of data using Marshal.AllocHGlobal and copy the header into it with Marshal.StructureToPtr.  The IntPtr from the AllocHGlobal then is passed into waveOutPrepareHeader as such and that resolved the issue.

Here's some rough sample code for any who run up against a similar problem.

```
WAVEHDR header = new WAVEHDR();
//Read or setup header data here
IntPtr headerPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(header));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(header, headerPtr, true);
waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, headerPtr, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(header));
```

This assumes that you set your PInvoke for everything that uses the header to an IntPtr type instead of a WAVEHDR one.

From there, use the headerPtr for all the places where you need to pass in that header.  You'll have to handle the freeing of memory yourself at the appropriate location as you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

Is your sample size bigger than 1 byte? If so then ...

on ARM it is important to keep data aligned, so if you allocate BYTE (one byte) buffer and later cast it to SHORT (two bytes), then if BYTE buffer was allocated on odd address then you will get unaligned data access.

So if your sample size is two bytes then you must ensure that your BYTE buffer address is always even.

To verify this you can check what value does lpData  have when error appears, if it is odd then simply allocate 1 byte more and send buffer+1 to winapi function.

---

below is sample code with proper alignment, found at:
http://www.utdallas.edu/~nsg051000/AmbientNoise4/Wave.cs

```
    ///  
    /// Read a data buffer from the supplied BinaryReader.  This method will 
    /// allocate memory for the data buffer it is not already allocated. 
    ///  
    /// BinaryReader containing data 
    /// Size, in bytes, to be read 
    /// MMSYSERR.NOERROR if successful 
    public MMSYSERR Read(BinaryReader rdr, uint readLength, int align)
    {
        uint bufferLength = readLength;

        if (bufferLength % align != 0)
            bufferLength += (uint)(align - (bufferLength % align));

        dwBufferLength = bufferLength;
        byte[] data = new byte[readLength];
        rdr.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

        if (lpData == IntPtr.Zero)
            lpData = Memory.LocalAlloc(Memory.LMEM_FIXED, (uint)bufferLength);

        if (lpData == IntPtr.Zero)
            return MMSYSERR.NOMEM;

        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, lpData, data.Length);

        return MMSYSERR.NOERROR;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried the code with Waves with four byte blocks and two byte blocks, but all my lpData so far has been an even value and divisible by the appropriate block number.  Is an IntPtr the actual memory address when working in C#?

Comment: I dont do much c# programming, I have found sample code: http://www.utdallas.edu/~nsg051000/AmbientNoise4/Wave.cs that might help you, what differs from your code is that it aligns buffer lenght before use. I am putting read() function in Answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, trying that code ends up going over the adjustment as 32768 % 2, 4, 16, and 32 (wasn't sure if align was bits or bytes) all come back 0

Comment: Have you tried using Marshal.AllocHGlobal? It all seems to be OK as I see.

Comment: What would I use AllocHGlobal in place of?  I saw a couple examples that used it but it didn't seem to be directly doing much.  Would it be to allocate the Header location?  (unfortunately I won't be back at the CE device I've been working on until Monday at this point so testing is more difficult)

Comment: AllocHGlobal ended up being the solution.  While the lpData variable was being set correctly, I needed to take the actual structure for the header and put it into a block of data which I had a pointer via Marshal.StructureToPtr, then pass that into the waveOutPrepareHeader function.  I'll compile all this into an answer a bit later for future issue seekers, unless you'd like to so you can get the points from it.  Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: nice, no problem - write your answer